# Share annotated PDF from iOS

Tags: ios, pdf, preview

When I annotate a PDF file, the annotations are correctly saved and can be seen using iOS "files" when saved there.

But, when I upload the annotated PDF on the web, or by email, the annotations aren’t there anymore.

But, when saved again in "files", the annotations appears again.

How can I annotate a PDF using iOS preview, and share them by email to anyone who has or hasn’t iOS ?

Comment: How do you verify that the annotations aren't there anymore? - I.e. the email you send, which OS, mail client and PDF viewer do you use to open it?

Comment: When I upload it on a website, it’s not shown on the browser pdf reader plugin. When by email, using Outlook iOS. My real goal is to share the annotated PDF by uploading it on our website. Is there a way to "flatten" the annotation from iOS? I don’t need them separated, but really merged

Comment: Which browser and which plugin? What happens if you open the file in Preview on a Mac?

Comment: When I upload it on a website (using iOS Safari), and download it again on my Mac (using Safari and Preview) then no annotation are shown. If I transfer the file to my Mac with Airdrop, then I can see them in Preview